# VS 2017 Конкретно в моей программе не видит Capture

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2017, камера, emgucv

Ошибка  CS0246  Не удалось найти тип или имя пространства имен "Capture" (возможно, отсутствует директива using или ссылка на сборку).

Comment: Хм...а ребилд не спасает? Возможно у вас установлена совсем *голая* версия VS и нужно доставить компонент.

Comment: Нет такого я думаю не может быть...Я устанавливал все пакеты при установке

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iqO5CSm5kpM

Comment: Это лекция по которой я примерно делал проект...Примерно на 36 мин будет сам код(там все работает)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас в коде имеется два использования библиотеки, в которой имеется тип `Capture`. Первый принадлежит сборке `Emgu.CV`:

- [Emgu CV Library Documentation: Capture Class](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.0.0.0/html/18b6eba7-f18b-fa87-8bf2-2acff68988cb.htm)

а второй принадлежит сборке `System`:

- [Пространство имен: System.Text.RegularExpressions: Класс Capture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.text.regularexpressions.capture(v=vs.110).aspx)

Либо, это свойство, которое принадлежит сборке `System.Windows.Forms`:

- [System.Windows.Forms: Свойство Control.Capture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.capture(v=vs.110).aspx)

Так как в метках вопроса вы указали `Emgu.CV`, то скорее всего искомый `Capture` должен принадлежать именно этому пространсву имен. Чтобы код заработал - вам необходимо явным образом указать пространство имен для типа `Capture`, для этого, достаточно объявление типа:

```
Capture capture = ...
```

заменить на:

```
Emgu.CV.Capture capture = ...
```

В общем, нужно разобраться, к какому пространству имен принадлежит тип, на объявлении которого падает ошибка и задать ему необходимый.